# Sending request using $.ajax to rails controller

Tags: jquery, jrubyonrails

I am using Rails 3 with JQuery.

I have two variables, which I want to send from my javascript code to the controller and render my views so that they have new values of the variables.

My request in javascript looks like this:

```
function sendGPToServer(title, address) 14     {
      var dataString = 'name=' + title + '&address=' + address;
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/search",
          data: dataString,
          success: function() {
              alert("succeeded!");
          }
      });
```

In pages controller (where the search action lives) I have

```
protect_from_forgery :except => [:search]
```

so it shouldn't be security problem.

I get the "succeeded!" message but *search* does not get called. But if I *reload* the home page manually the values of the variables are filled in to my website page as I wanted.

Does anyone know why can this be happening? Can it be because my javascript is included to the header of my html layout?

(also: in routes.rb I have changed *pages/search* to *search* so it should not be a problem)

Thank you

Comment: Try adding an error() handler so you can see if it's 404ing/500ing

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect that your variables get assigned if you don't do anything inside the sucess callback function ?

If you have the success function executed it means that the method responding to that URL (with GET requests) has being called and it has returned *something* in response (maybe also just an empy HTTP 200).

If I was you I would have a look on what your controller method returns and on how to use it in the situation you need (f.i. returning json and use it somehow / render some js ... )

Comment: The thing is that when I get variables values I use methods to set a value of variables. Then whenever my page is rendered again views themselves notice that the values have changed and writes different values on the pages.

I think that there is no point to try render something from the controller if the controller action does not get called anyway.

Comment: If ajax's success function is called it means that "someone" sent a response back to that request. Have a better look and be sure on who is answering (firebug can help here since you can see response's content). Also rake routes or assert_generates can help (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes) do check that the route is weel configured.